# P0302 error code Nissan Primera p12

Tags: engine, nissan, misfire

I own a 2004 Nissan Primera P12 with the 1.8 litre.

My car MIL started glowing for two weeks. I read the code it was P0302 which is misfire in cylinder 2.

I checked ignition coil and spark plug. I swapped around to see if that's the problem, but still it reports P0302.

I took the car to garage today. The mechanic diagnosed it and said low or no pressure in cylinder 2. He said there is no point in servicing further as the cost will be higher and it's not worth it to spend on this car so he asked me to exchange or sell the car.

I bought this car 8 months back so I don't want to buy another one within a year.  Insurance is pretty expensive.

- Can I go for servicing it further?  Maybe fixing the actual root cause or change the engine?
- Engine oil burns so if I can fix first problem, I can invest in fixing this.  I assume this might be problem with gasket or piston rings.
- If nothing is possible, can I drive the car few more months, maybe 2000 miles with this condition?

Any other thoughts is also highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you clear the obd2 error code after you swapped ig coils and plugs around? What did plug 2 look like?